# Handling HTTP redirects in AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, audio, avplayer, avqueueplayer

I have an application that can play an audio playlist using an `AVQueuePlayer`.

The actual song's URLs are built dynamically and expires after a certain period of time after being built. So the playlist is constructed using something like a permalink, where the song URL is permanent, and responds with an HTTP status code of 301.

Say, for example, that the song URL is *http://myhost.com/song?id=1234*, and that URL responds with a 301 (moved permanently) and a Location header with a URL that looks like *http://realcontent.com/song?id=...&token=...*

This all works fine, the music gets played, but I'm experiencing a delay of a few seconds before the audio starts playing.

What I see is that the AVPlayer is doing:

1. a first request with HTTP header "Range: bytes=0-1" to the permalink, it responds with the redirect,
2. a request to the redirected URL with the same range
3. a sencond request to the permalink with the full range, that gets redirected
4. a second request to the redirected URL with the full range.

I would like to avoid the third step, as it is completely unnecessary. The permalink already responded with ***moved permanently***, so the following request will respond the same way.

Is there a setting or something I can change to avoid making that request?